# get facebook users data of his reads in washington post or yahoo reader

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to get the reads of a user in washington post or yahoo reader?
I have checked http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ where one gets access to news feed and profile feed, but they dont gives  what the user has read in washington post / yahoo reader. Is there any way to get this information using javascript jdk?

What I have tried:
After login in thorugh the login in button. I query

```
FB.api('/me/washington_posts', function(response) { 
    var wash_post=JSON.stringify(response); 
    alert(wash_post); 
});
graph.facebook.com/me/317071798339058?access_token=AAAAAAITEghM...
graph.facebook.com/me/...
```

I tried sevaral combinations of washington_posts, but always got error. I know this was not going to work but tried for some luck There is no documentaion of the same as mentioned here. 
I believe its not possible to get it as of now as wpsocialreader is a diiferent fb app. `apps.facebook.com/wpsocialreader/…` I am only able to get the app info.

`graph.facebook.com/267401179951379` :

```
{ "id": "267401179951379", "name": "Washington Post Social Reader", "link": "facebook.com/wpsocialreader";, "likes": 169544, "category": "App", "is_published": true, "website": "washingtonpost.com/socialreader";, "username": "wpsocialreader", "description": ".........", "about": "News. Better with friends. ", "release_date": "2011", "can_post": true, "talking_about_count": 19977 }
```

I think it is not possible to collect data from washington post reader app, so I am looking if somebody have already done it.

Comment: Are you talking about trying to get the new user/action/object Open Graph? What would be the namespace be Washington Post / Yahoo reader?  I presume their verb would be "read", right?

Comment: I am not sure...I tried several namespace and {action-type}/{object-type} but didnt succeed. May anyone please point me to the right one.

Comment: So let me understand this.  You don't see any documentation on how to do something.  You don't understand what it is.  You haven't tried anything. And you want us to help?  Please kindly ready about how to ask questions on StackOverflow: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask and http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.  Thanks

Comment: I have tried several combinations and wasnt able to get the correct response.So I posted here if anyone has already tried this before as I didnt find any relevant questions before.

Comment: Edit your question with the code and the documentation you used.  Let us know the errors you received.

Comment: After login in thorugh the login in button. I query

   FB.api('/me/washington_posts', function(response) {

      var wash_post=JSON.stringify(response);

      alert(wash_post);

     });

https://graph.facebook.com/me/317071798339058?access_token=AAAAAAITEghM.......

https://graph.facebook.com/me/wpsocialreader?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAI.......


I tried sevaral combinations of washington_posts, but always got error. I know this was not going to work but tried for some luck
There is no documentaion of the same as mentioned here. Hence I posted here.

Comment: I believe its not possible to get it as of now as wpsocialreader is a diiferent fb app.
http://apps.facebook.com/wpsocialreader/?fb_action_ids=317071798339058&fb_action_types=news.reads&fb_source=other_multiline
I am only able to get the app info. https://graph.facebook.com/267401179951379

Comment: {
   "id": "267401179951379",
   "name": "Washington Post Social Reader",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/wpsocialreader",
   "likes": 169544,
   "category": "App",
   "is_published": true,
   "website": "http://www.washingtonpost.com/socialreader",
   "username": "wpsocialreader",
   "description": ".........",
   "about": "News. Better with friends. ",
   "release_date": "2011",
   "can_post": true,
   "talking_about_count": 19977
}



I think it is not possible to collect data from washington post reader app, so I am looking if somebody have already done it.

Comment: Please edit the question with this additional information so it can be seen clearly.  That will help people be able to better help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the entries with the open graph action type news.read from yourself or a friend using the graph API:

graph.facebook.com/me/news.reads or graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/news.reads

Obviously, add in the access token and other graph parameters you need as well. This will return all reads from the applications that publish them. You could then pick out the social reader reads by app id.

Hope this helps.

-matt